# Getting following 'Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /path/spring-instrument-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar' in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, jar

sharing VM option as below

```
-javaagent:"/Users/suygupta/Desktop/spring-instrument-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar"
-Dserver.port=8080
-Duser.timezone=UTC
-Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

Also, spring-instrument-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar file has all the permission for current user.mac os and build tool used is gradle.

Comment: Please add more information. When do you get this error? Do you use any build tool (Maven, Gradle)?

Comment: updated it @y.bedrov

Comment: Realised that even though current user have permission for jar files but IntelliJ(opened by same current user) does not have permission somehow. Reinstallation of intellij helped.